# Homebrew setup is not working

Tags: ruby, macos, curl, homebrew

My Homebrew setup is broken. My brew commands are not working, so I am trying to install a new one using:

```
ruby -e “$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)”
```

but it says:

```
It appears Homebrew is already installed. If your intent is to reinstall you
should do the following before running this installer again:

ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
```

and when I try to uninstall I get this message:

```
Failed to locate Homebrew!
```

I am also getting some mail in my shell mail box saying:

```
Subject: Cron <khemkv02@MC-S089998> /usr/local/Cellar/openssl-osx-ca/1.0.5    /bin/openssl-osx-ca /usr/local/bin/brew
X-Cron-Env: < SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: < PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: < LOGNAME=khemkv02>
X-Cron-Env: < USER=khemkv02>
X-Cron-Env: < HOME=/Users/khemkv02>
Message-Id: <20150929150001.D9295FF315@MC-S089998.local>
Date: Tue, 29 Sep 2015 16:00:00 +0100 (BST)
**Homebrew not in PATH or given arguments, cannot continue**
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: What output do you get when you run `brew doctor`?

Comment: Have you looked at this homebrew uninstall script? https://gist.github.com/mxcl/1173223

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete `.git`:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/.git
```

Because I found the message, **Homebrew is already installed**, in the `install` script:

```
abort <<-EOABORT unless Dir["#{HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/.git/*"].empty?
    It appears Homebrew is already installed. If your intent is to reinstall you
    should do the following before running this installer again:
    ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
EOABORT
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I managed to uninstall homebrew. cheers.